# Running GO GET SDL2 Error executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, sdl-2

Im simplly trying to install `go-sdl2` on MACOX from https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2#installation

`go get -v github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/{sdl,img,mix,ttf}`

I get following ERROR:

```
github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
# pkg-config --cflags sdl2
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```